# Not able to enable text box using mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am able to disable a text box using mootools but after disabling it I am not able to enable it back.
Please see the code underneath.

Here 'mg' is id of a text box.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){

    $('mg').setAttribute('disabled','true');
    //$('mg').disabled = false  this works fine
    //does not enable text box
    $('mg').setAttribute('disabled','false');
});
```

Here is jsfiddle link.
http://jsfiddle.net/GgyCH/2/
please help me out on this.Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using mootools you can use Element method [set](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:set), to actually set attributes, like so http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/p6BDb/

js:

```
var elem = $('mg');
elem.set('disabled','disabled'); //disable
elem.set('disabled',''); //enable
```

Answer (score 0):

Use: `$('mg').setAttribute('disabled','');`

(or just remove the attribute)

"disabled", like "selected" is not a true/false attribute. It should actually be:

`$('mg').setAttribute('disabled','disabled');` to set it

Answer (score 0):

just change the value directly in the attribute of the object

```
alert($('mg').disabled);
$('mg').disabled = true;
alert( $('mg').disabled);
$('mg').disabled = false;
alert($('mg').disabled);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GgyCH/3/

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Javascript 101:

```
$('mg').setAttribute('disabled', true);
$('mg').removeAttribute('disabled');
```